# SwiftUI how to add an Underline to a Text View?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there a way to modify a Text view to have an underline? For example like this text below:

y͟o͟u͟r͟ t͟e͟x͟t͟

```
Text(Constants.chooseText)
    .font(Font.system(size: 26))
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .padding(.bottom, 80)
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Add the underline modifier, on the Text View

```swift
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .underline()
```

Comment: underline is available after ios16. what to do if we need to use before ios 16

Comment: @PoojaGupta underline has been available since iOS 13.0+ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text/underline(_:color:)

Comment: @PoojaGupta is right! Look at this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/underline(_:pattern:color:)

Comment: @PoojaGupta, you need to apply .underline() method right below the Text() to be available on iOS 13.0, otherwise it will be available on iOS 16.0 because we considered apply .underline() to the View() instead of the Text()

Answer (score 14):

UPDATE adding underline() as the first modifier solved the issue.

```
Text(Constants.chooseText)
    .underline()
    .font(Font.system(size: 26))
    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    .padding(.bottom, 80)
```

Answer (score 10):

**iOS 16**
you can use the **underline** modifier, If you want anything more advanced like control its position and size, then you can use the **background** modifier, and in the bg you can set the **height**, **offset**, and **color** of the underline. Alternatively, you can also use the **overlay** modifier. Sample Code:

```
// Using background modifier
                    Text("FRANCE")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .background(
                            Color.white
                                .frame(height: 1) // underline's height
                                .offset(y: 14) // underline's y pos
                        )
```

**Output:**
[image]

```
//Using overlay modifier
              Text("FRANCE")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .overlay(
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(Color.white)
                                .frame(width: 64, height: 1)
                            , alignment: .bottom
                        )
```

**Output:** [image]

Answer (score 6):

**You may use below like:**

```
Text("Forget User ID")
     .underline(true, color: .gray)
```